# numberOfLines in child Text

Tags: css, react-native

I need to limit the size of `longText` but still show time in the end. I found out `numberOfLines` can only work in the parent Text component.

Here's part of the code:

```
<Text style={components.text} isBold={true}>
   {boldText}
   <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode='tail'> 
     {longText}
   </Text>
   <Text> {time}</Text>
</Text>


text: {
   fontSize: 14,    
   flexDirection: "row",
   width: "80%",
```

I already tried setting the parent to `View` but them the time is not exactly after the `longText`, which is what I need.

Basically I need something like:

**bold part of the text** tesnfskd nfskld kfnslnflskd

fnsdkl dasnkl dnakl ndsaln ndklas ndkals nkdsn ... 9h

Comment: You can use `.slice()` method to limit the `longText`.

Comment: Not sure how this works, but I am guess this probably applies the `line-clamp` CSS property to the element ...? Then what you want is hardly possible, I think, without involving a lot of trickery. Even having the bold text and the beginning of the `{longText}` in one line isn't really possible with _that_ structure, I think (line-clamp needs to be applied on a "block" element to begin with) - you'd have to move the bold text into the one you're applying this to.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in a `Row` like this and position the text element at `flex-end`.. should do the trick!

```
 <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginHorizontal: 10, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text numberOfLines={2}>{'some bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla'}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text>{'9h'}</Text>
  </View>
```